# c# System Methods && LINQ implementations

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to see how LINQ expressions are implemented? (Eg. Union / Intersect, Where etc). That would be very helpful because sometimes LINQ executes faster than custom code and sometimes it doesn't. It would be nice to know from the beginning what to use.

I know there's also tool which allows you to see .NET System methods implementations, but i can't remember its name. Can anyone point me to that?

Thank you!

Comment: For an in-depth discussion of how LINQ *could* be implemented -- although not necessarily how the BCL version actually *is* implemented -- you might be interested in Jon Skeet's [series of Edulinq articles](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know there's also tool which allows you to see .NET System methods
>   implementations, but i can't remember its name.

The in-memory extension methods are implemented in the [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) class in the `System.Core` assembly.

- [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) is one example of a tool that allows you to easily inspect implementation given a compiled assembly.
- [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) is a free alternative.

But the .NET source code is now [freely available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rscc/archive/2010/08/16/net-framework-4-reference-source-is-available.aspx). So don't hesitate to directly consult it.

Answer (score 1):

Use free decompiler [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). It's also is built in ReSharper